# Using Yum to deploy web application on different machines

Tags: linux, java, yum, deployment

I want to deploy application on different machine with Yum. According to my learning I have to create yum repository and package of application. But I cannot find relationship between package and repository. I mean do not know where I have to place web application or make any package of it. Also I am confuse in YUM commands. Please explain me in points. Appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yum works with RPM packages. This might be helpful to create a new RPM: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/.

For a short guide on how to create yum repositories, read http://www.webmo.net/support/yum_repository.html

Especially the first link helped me to create an RPM package, but it's a long time since I done this.